# jQuery cookie expiry time

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I was able to set a cookie using jQuery with a redirect to a landing page but I have no idea how can I set the cookie expiry date to less then one day (for example 15 minutes). I was not able to find explanation in the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'splash-page-cookie';
    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    if ($go == null) {
        $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: 1 });
        window.location = "/example"
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Thank you for all help !

**EDIT:**
I was able to set cookie as session cookie by skipping expire, well im fine with that but its not perfect, if you guys have some idea i would be grateful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plugins `expires` option accepts either a number or a date object.

If a number is passed, it's the number of days until the cookie expires, but if a date object is passed, it's the time and date when the cookie expires, so you can do

```
var expDate = new Date();

expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (15 * 60 * 1000)); // add 15 minutes

$.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: expDate });
```

Answer (score 10):

A fraction of a day should work, so for example there are 1440 minutes in a day so if you wanted the cookie to expire in 15 minutes you could simply divide the minutes by 1440 like so:

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: 15/1440});
```

This would also work with hours, so for example if you wanted the cookie to expire in 2 hours you could do:

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: 2/24});
```

A third option is to pass a date object like so:

```
var expire = new Date();

//set expiry to current time plus 15 minutes in milliseconds
expire.setTime(expire.getTime() + (15 * 60 * 1000)); 

$.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: expire});
```

Hope this helps!